# It is secure to expose email address on router code?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Using this code for Google OAuthentication

```
// Authenticate route with bifurcation for admin and general users
// Solution based on:
// http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/#custom-callback
router.get('/google/callback', (req, res, next) =>
  passport.authenticate('google', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if  (!user) return res.redirect('/login');

    req.logIn(user, err => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if (req.user.email === 'adminemail@adminemail.com') return res.redirect('/admin');
      return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
  })(req, res, next)
);
```

Of course only the admin email is exposed, not password at all.

Anyway, It is secure to expose email address on router code?

Or do I need to write the email as a global var or another trick?

Comment: The code will be executed on the server so it's not going to expose the email to any users, but it would still be better practice to have it stored in a variable, maybe an array of admin users so it can be extended.

Comment: @braza thanks, if you put your text as an answer I can mark it as the solution

Comment: Great, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will be executed on the server so it's not going to expose the email to any users.

This being said, it would still be better practice to have it stored in a variable such as an array of admin users so it can be extended if you ever have more users.